# How to pragmatically send a question to MS Azure chat bot ( in direcline channel ) using client side script

Tags: javascript, jquery, botframework

I'm using Azure Chat bot (v4 MS bot framework) and applied in Direcline channel, and I want to send the question to chatbot when user clicking on the suggested questions.

in the below image, you can see the suggested questions here, when users clicks on these suggested question, that question is getting added to the input box, but the same is sent to the bot, instead that few letters only sent to the bot.

[image]
I used the following code

```
$('i.probing').click(function() {
  document.querySelectorAll('[aria-label="Sendbox"]')[0].value =(this.innerText);
  $('.css-115fwte').trigger('click');
});
```

With this code the value is getting entered in the input box, however the bot does not received any question, and hence it failed to answer.

this is how it will in console after adding the question by script.

[image]

its seems like that the value in the UI is not reflecting in the backend.
can anyone please let me know what is wrong with my approach.

Comment: By "suggested questions", do you mean [Suggested Actions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-howto-add-suggested-actions?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=csharp)? I just want to be sure we're talking about the same thing. If not, can you expand on what user interaction you're hoping for? Pictures and code will help.

Comment: @mdrichardson-MSFT, thanks for replying, not that suggested actions of chat bot, my requirement is simple and as you mentioned i've modified the question with required screenshots, hope it will be clear now

Comment: I see what you mean. I can help you with that, but honestly, using Suggested Actions would be a better way to do this since it accomplishes the same thing and is built in to the SDK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per my comments, I recommend using Suggested Actions for something like this. Otherwise, you could do something like [this Web Chat Sample](https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/tree/master/samples/04.api/d.post-activity-event):

```js
        document.querySelector('#helpButton').addEventListener('click', () => {
          store.dispatch({
            type: 'WEB_CHAT/SEND_MESSAGE',
            payload: { text: 'help' }
          });
        });
```

Just change `#helpButton` to whatever your querySelector would be. I believe you're using `i.probing`

Comment: @mdrichrdson thanks for helping me, your approach is working , however its not fixing my issue,  becasue in my bot, I already used this 'store' approach to send the welcome message, (how to use it again please provide me the syntax ) and i cant create a button element out of the chat bot, In my bot I've appended the suggested questions in the bot itself, so the element will be created after the bot loads, hence we can say that the element is dynamic. so where will I've to write this on click event, ?

Comment: @JeganBaskaran Please include your current store code and I can ensure that I provide you a working example. Might be easiest if you just post your whole html file (after removing your token).

Comment: thanks for replying, I've added the full code and explained [my_question_ in _a_better_way_here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59942319/how-to-send-a-message-to-direct-line-chat-bot-from-the-ui-using-javascript) , please check and help me.

Comment: @JeganBaskaran Although we didn't get this fully working through this questions/answer, would you consider "accepting" it? If you believe it needs additional information, let me know and I'll edit it in.

Comment: i should accept this answer, and if someone who want to view the problem and solution in a bigger picture they can use this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59942319/how-to-send-a-message-to-direct-line-chat-bot-from-the-ui-using-javascript/59955217?noredirect=1#comment106058102_59955217) where you gave the detailed answer